# What is the wordpress page title php code?

Tags: title

I have a header file in WordPress theme which always shows site title after the creation of a new page because of code  `<?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>` but I want it to replace with current page title instate of site name so, what would be PHP code for that?

Comment: Are you referring to the `<title>` tag?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
global $post;
echo esc_html( get_the_title($post->ID) );
```